# R : How to config ggplotly displaying values on the line graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My plot on ggplotly shows unnecessary info while cursor pointing on the line graph. 
[image]
Here is my example code :

```
df <- read.table(text="
                              DateTime,Val1,Val2
                 1  ,2017-07-01 09:32:00      ,401.7542   ,275.5876
                 2  ,2017-07-01 09:30:00      ,402.7049   ,359.2615
                 3  ,2017-07-01 09:29:00      ,402.5912   ,276.4372
                 4  ,2017-07-01 09:28:00      ,402.7526   ,362.6202
                 5  ,2017-07-01 09:27:00      ,402.4538   ,361.3867
                 6  ,2017-07-01 09:26:00      ,401.8847   ,359.6318
                 7  ,2017-07-01 09:25:00      ,402.2666   ,274.8941
                 8  ,2017-07-01 09:24:00      ,403.0774   ,277.4844
                 9  ,2017-07-01 09:23:00      ,403.0516   ,363.3593
                 10 ,2017-07-01 09:22:00      ,402.5764   ,275.4202
                 11 ,2017-07-01 09:21:00      ,402.2379   ,275.0550
                 12 ,2017-07-01 09:20:00      ,401.9060   ,277.2950
                 13 ,2017-07-01 09:19:00      ,401.9451   ,361.0770
                 14 ,2017-07-01 09:18:00      ,401.4484   ,361.3591
                 15 ,2017-07-01 09:17:00      ,402.5519   ,274.8206
                 16 ,2017-07-01 09:16:00      ,402.1426   ,279.2438
                 17 ,2017-07-01 09:15:00      ,402.4618   ,360.7491
                 18 ,2017-07-01 09:14:00      ,403.3124   ,276.4756
                 19 ,2017-07-01 09:13:00      ,402.3604   ,276.7015
                 20 ,2017-07-01 09:12:00      ,402.5518   ,363.2422
                 21 ,2017-07-01 09:11:00      ,404.7830   ,360.2075
                 22 ,2017-07-01 09:10:00      ,403.7317   ,275.8560
                 23 ,2017-07-01 09:09:00      ,403.2151   ,276.8633
                 24 ,2017-07-01 09:08:00      ,404.2897   ,361.6937
                 25 ,2017-07-01 09:07:00      ,403.8227   ,355.2353
                 26 ,2017-07-01 09:06:00      ,402.8998   ,276.0700
                 27 ,2017-07-01 09:05:00      ,403.1328   ,362.2495
                 28 ,2017-07-01 09:04:00      ,404.1612   ,361.9048
                 29 ,2017-07-01 09:03:00      ,403.7537   ,274.9531
                 30 ,2017-07-01 09:02:00      ,402.1621   ,360.7682
                 31 ,2017-07-01 09:01:00      ,403.0805   ,360.8172
                 32 ,2017-07-01 09:00:00      ,403.3630   ,276.2874
                 33 ,2017-07-01 08:59:00      ,402.8351   ,275.9734
                 34 ,2017-07-01 08:58:00      ,403.6484   ,360.5585
                 35 ,2017-07-01 08:57:00      ,403.4342   ,357.7776
                 36 ,2017-07-01 08:56:00      ,402.4444   ,275.8763
                 37 ,2017-07-01 08:55:00      ,403.2913   ,361.2458
                 38 ,2017-07-01 08:54:00      ,403.2985   ,276.7728
                 39 ,2017-07-01 08:53:00      ,403.2600   ,276.6644
                 40 ,2017-07-01 08:52:00      ,401.9991   ,361.2737
                 41 ,2017-07-01 08:51:00      ,404.9158   ,358.2727
                 42 ,2017-07-01 08:50:00      ,403.8922   ,357.0592
                 43 ,2017-07-01 08:49:00      ,403.0070   ,359.5312
                 44 ,2017-07-01 08:48:00      ,404.8530   ,360.1790
                 45 ,2017-07-01 08:47:00      ,404.1543   ,359.4836
                 46 ,2017-07-01 08:46:00      ,403.9200   ,357.9064
                 47 ,2017-07-01 08:45:00      ,403.9197   ,358.6364
                 48 ,2017-07-01 08:44:00      ,406.0925   ,358.6248
                 49 ,2017-07-01 08:43:00      ,401.5529   ,359.9990
                 50 ,2017-07-01 08:42:00      ,402.4422   ,356.6060",sep=",",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(df$DateTime)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(DateTime)) + ylab("Val") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Val1, col = "Val1"),lwd=0.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Val2, col = "Val2"),lwd=0.5) +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%m-%d %H:%M"),expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,10))  +
  theme(text = element_text(size=9),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        legend.text = element_text(size=10),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = 'grey75', size = 0.2))
ggplotly(p) %>% config(displayModeBar = FALSE) %>% layout(xaxis=list(fixedrange=TRUE)) %>% layout(yaxis=list(fixedrange=TRUE))
```

So how to config format displaying weekdays instead of date and hide that unnecessary line or hide both these 2 info-lines including DateTime to show only Val?

My expected output :
[image]

Thanks so much for your helps in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ggplotly` call you can add a 'tooltip' argument that defines which values show up in the tooltip. To customize this tooltip we can add a `text` aesthetic to the ggplot call. ggplot will ignore this (and throw a warning that it's doing so) but in the `ggplotly` call you can add `tooltip = c("y","text")` and it will put `text` in the tooltip. Now all we need to do is define `text` to be the dateformat you want and we have the desired tooltip.

Code: Note that I also had to add `group = 1` to the aesthetic, If you don't add this it will try and plot each point as a separate line, resulting in an empty graph.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(DateTime)) + ylab("Val") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Val1, col = "Val1", text = paste("DateTime:", format(DateTime, "%A %T")), group = 1),lwd=0.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Val2, col = "Val2", text = paste("DateTime:", format(DateTime, "%A %T")), group = 1),lwd=0.5) +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%m-%d %H:%M"),expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,10))  +
  theme(text = element_text(size=9),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        legend.text = element_text(size=10),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = 'grey75', size = 0.2))
ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("y","text")) %>% config(displayModeBar = FALSE) %>% layout(xaxis=list(fixedrange=TRUE)) %>% layout(yaxis=list(fixedrange=TRUE))
```

Plot:
[image: Fixed tooltip]

Answer (score 3):

If you reflow your data into long format, the problem appears to go away.

```
library(tidyr)
xy <- gather(df, key = group, value = value, -DateTime)

p <- ggplot(xy, aes(DateTime, y = value, color = group)) + ylab("Val") +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%m-%d %H:%M"),expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,10))  +
  theme(text = element_text(size=9),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        legend.text = element_text(size=10),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = 'grey75', size = 0.2))
ggplotly(p) %>% config(displayModeBar = FALSE) %>% layout(xaxis=list(fixedrange=TRUE)) %>% layout(yaxis=list(fixedrange=TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, and how can I config it to add format weekdays to display with DateTime on the line graph.

Comment: @SirawitTakeo please search the forum, this is a standard question. If you can't get it to work, post another question.